# android: how to make @String/name work in res folder?

Tags: android, xml, string

Android
I got the following code in an xml file in the res folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<designs>
 <design name="2Parts">
     <module id="0" posY="0" posX="0" height="0.5" width="1" capHeight="0.2"></module>
     <module id="1" posY="0.5" posX="0" height="0.66" width="1" capHeight="0.2"></module>         
 </design>
```

Instead of using height="0.5" I'd like to have a variable from the Strings like height="@string/height_one" . But somehow I can't use the @string function.
Is that possible?

Is there an easy way to calculate with the strings in other files?
For an example :

```
height="@string/height_one * 0.5" ?
```

Looking forward to your answers

Comment: Why you need to do it ? Mean to say What is your requirement ?

Comment: which part?
The usage of @string is supposed to calculate every height regarding on starting number for several designs
and that is why I would like to calculate numbers from a String...

Comment: no ideas? Can't I use the @string method somehow?